# Mostrar mais precisão em C++

Tags: c++, matemática

Tenho este programa:

```
int main(){
    double x=2;
    cout << sqrt(x);
}
```

Gostaria de mostrar o resultado com a máxima precisão possível. Obrigado!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utiliza `setprecision` desta forma:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>           // Para ter a máxima precisão

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double x=2;
    cout << setprecision(numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10) << sqrt(x);
}
```

Comment: Funciona. Mas há alguma forma de se obter a precisão máxima?

Comment: @AlephZero Sim, há. Tens de usar numeric_limits<double>. Já editei.

Answer (score 6):

Pode fazer assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double num = sqrt(2);
    cout << fixed;
    cout.precision(52);
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9Kd3rX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rfavxwea-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/Precison.cpp).

Comment: Uma dúvida, se a norma IEEE 754 de 2008, que define a representação de números de ponto flutuante de precisão dupla (64 bits), fornece uma relativa precisão de cerca de 16 dígitos decimais e intervalo de magnitude de 10^-308 a 10^+308, de onde vem esta quantidade de algarismos exibidas pelo programa? Para uma precisão maior não seria necessário utilizar alguma das bibliotecas que implementam representações de números decimais de precisão arbitrária (por exemplo GMP - The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library ) e não o tipo de dado double?